# nginx with react-router /api is a 404 page

Tags: reactjs, nginx, docker-compose, react-router

I'm making a multi container app, react with nginx on front and spring boot on backend.

Before adding nginx I had **localhost:3000** as my react app, with **localhost:8080** as my spring API. In **3000/themes** I could see the react page and with **/themes** I could access the API because **localhost:8080** was the proxy line in package.json.

Adapting this to a docker-compose context I changed to this code below, but in **localhost:80/themes** I can only access the API, and this is expected. If I put the line
**"proxy_pass http://backend;"** in a **"location /api {}"**, when access **localhost/api**, I'll get my personalized 404 page, because **/api** is not a route in react-route and shouldn't be.
What I want to have a non-react route to serve my api like **"http:backend/api"** in the proxy line, and in **"localhost/themes"** have my themes page, and in a child component access **"/themes"** and get this API from **localhost:8080/themes** as I can access from postman.

My nginx.conf right now is:

```
upstream backend {
    server app-server:8080;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
     
    error_page 401 403 404 index.html;   

    location /public {
        root /usr/local/var/www;
    }
}
```

And my package.json proxy line is:

```
"proxy": "http://backend",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add add a named location for `proxy_pass`, and append it as the last argument of `try_files`

```
upstream backend {
    server app-server:8080;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy-backend;    
    }

    location @proxy-backend {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
     
    error_page 401 403 404 index.html;   

    location /public {
        root /usr/local/var/www;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!